# only get the full path from a string, without preceding url

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have the string

```
"https://www.example.com/example/path.php"
```

... for example.

How would I only get the final path's from the string (so only `example/path.php`)?

I have seem some regex which semi-achieves what I'm looking for, however, it'll only ever get rid of the `https:`. The regex would work fine for `www.example.com/example/path.php`, but nothing else.

Essentially, **[original string]** -> **[new string]**

> https://www.example.com/example/path.php -> example/path.php
>
> www.example.com/example/path.php -> example/path.php
>
> /example/path.php -> example/path.php
>
> path.php -> path.php

Cheers.

Comment: Any attempts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You basically want to do `document.location.pathname` on any URL.

Comment: @JeremyThille Quentin's answer for one, and unfortunately - like the comments have suggested - it doesn't work as intended. I did end up attempting the Regex solution, however, as stated, that didn't work either.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's my go at it. Works with `http`, other domains such as `.org` and longer URLs :

```js
let domainMatch = /[a-z]{3}\.[a-z]{3,32}\.[a-z]{2,3}/,
  testStrings = ["https://www.example.com/example/path.php",
    "www.example.com/example/path.php",
    "/example/path.php",
    "path.php",
    "http://www.example.org/example1/example2/path.php"
  ]


let results = testStrings.map(str => 
  str.split("/")
      .filter(word => word.length && !(word.includes("http") || domainMatch.test(word)))
      .join("/")
)

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this perhaps (Solution without using `regex` or any APIs):

```js
let exclude = "www.example.com/";
let testURLs = ["https://www.example.com/example/path.php","www.example.com/example/path.php","/example/path.php","/example/example2/path.php","path.php"];

testURLs.forEach(url => {
 console.log(url.substring(url.indexOf(exclude) != -1 ? (url.indexOf(exclude) + exclude.length) : url.indexOf('/') != 0 ? 0 : 1 , url.length))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you consider the wanted part?

Is it the from second to last / to the end of the string?

You can split the string on / and then concat the last 2 parts with `/` in between.

```
var parts = window.location.href.split("/");
var result = parts[parts.length-2] + "/" + parts[parts.length-1];
```

If it's some constant part you wish to remove you can try:

```
var result = window.location.href.replace("constant part you wish to remove", "");
```

Comment: I also thought about that, but what about longer URLs? Like `/example1/example2/path.php`. It's not explicitely part of OP's question, but it might happen

Comment: I can hardly guess what does OP wanna till he defines  the "last part" better.  There could be also params in url behind this, should I or shouldnt I filter that? OR more importantly what does OP consider last part at all? I offered the option to remove static part of url as alternative.

Comment: Yes I agree, the question is a bit unclear/incomplete

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the first `/` that is not part of the protocol so ignore `//` if one is present and then just read past the next `/`

```js
var urls = ["https://www.example.com/example/path.php", "www.example.com/example/path.php", "/example/path.php", "path.php", "//www.xxx.com", "ftp://www.xxx.com/"];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var url = urls[i];
  
    // where to read from?
    var from = url.indexOf("//");
    from += (from >= 0 ? 2 : 1);

    // find the next / beyond that
    var to = url.indexOf("/", from);

    // read between, handling the case where / is the last character
    url = (from > 0 && to < 0) ? "" : url.substr(to + 1);
    
    console.log(urls[i], "=>", url);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[The URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) makes it easy to manipiulate URLs like this:

```js
["https://www.example.com/example/path.php", "www.example.com/example/path.php", "/example/path.php", "path.php"]
    .forEach(url => console.log(new URL(url, location.href).pathname));
```

… although it can't error correct for the URL which is missing the scheme before the hostname.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to using URL API (which isn't fully supported cross browser) , you can create an `<a>` element and set href attribute then get properties like `pathname` from that element.

*This solution lso fails for domain with no protocol* so that one you need to do some parsing/validation. A library like [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) would probably help you

If you know what the domain/host should be...then that would also be easy to check and set on the `<a>` when `a.host` isn't what is expected, same with  `a.protocol`

```js
["https://www.example.com/example/path.php", "www.example.com/example/path.php", "/example/path.php", "path.php"]
.forEach(url => {
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.setAttribute('href', url)
   console.log(a.pathname.slice(1));
});
```

Comment: Result 2 == `www.example.com/example/path.php`

Comment: @JeremyThille yes and that is also clarified in answer. I am not suggesting this is a complete url parser which is why I also suggested a library to assist. have no intentions of writing a full validator/parser

Comment: Yes, I also think that a robust solution requires a library.